# How to divide values in two field and insert the result to another field using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need to divide value of ProductID and Cost.

**Below is the example of my code :**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "testting";
$a = "calculationexample.ProductID";
$b = "calculationexample.Cost";
$c = "(a/b)";

try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception

$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "INSERT INTO calculationexample (ProductID, Cost, Ratio)
VALUES ('400', '200', '$c')";
// use exec() because no results are returned


$conn->exec($sql);
echo "New record created successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
?>
```

The value is inserted correctly for the field of ProductID, Cost EXCEPT for the Ratio field. Can anyone please show me the correct method?

Thank you.

=== QUESTIONS UPDATED ====

```
<?php

    require 'database.php';


    if ( !empty($_POST)) {
        // keep track validation errors
        $ProductIDError = null;
        $CostError = null;
        $MonthError = null


        // keep track post values
        $ProductID = $_POST['ProductID'];
        $Cost = $_POST['Cost'];
        $Month = $_POST['Month'];


        // validate input
        $valid = true;
        if (empty($ProductID)) {
            $ProductIDError = 'Please enter product id';
            $valid = false;
        }


        $valid = true;
        if (empty($Cost)) {
            $CostError = 'Please enter cost value';
            $valid = false;
        }


        $valid = true;
        if (empty($Month)) {
            $MonthError = 'Please enter cost value';
            $valid = false;
        }



$conn= new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//$var = "John"; // based on an id column (varchar)

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT Month,ProductID,Cost,Ratio FROM Inventory');
   // $stmt->bindValue(1, $var); 
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

$a = $row['ProductID'];
$b = $row['Cost'];
$m =$row['Month']
$c = ($a/$b);

//echo $c; // will output the ratio

            }
}



    try {



    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Inventory 
    (Month,ProductID, Cost, Ratio)
    VALUES(:Month, :ProductID, :Cost, :Ratio)");
    $stmt->bindValue(':Month', $m,PDO::PARAM_INT);    
    $stmt->bindValue(':ProductID', $a,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':Cost', $b,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':Ratio', $c,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

echo "New record created successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link   href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

                <div class="span10 offset1">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h3>Inventory</h3>
                    </div>



                    <form class="form-horizontal" action="division.php" method="post">

                      <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($MonthError)?'error':'';?>">
                        <label class="control-label">Month</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input name="month" type="text"  placeholder="Month" value="<?php echo !empty($m)?$m:'';?>">
                            <?php if (!empty($MonthError)): ?>
                                <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $MonthError;?></span>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                      </div>



                      <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($ProductID)?'error':'';?>">
                        <label class="control-label">ProductID</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input name="ProductID" type="text" placeholder="ProductID" value="<?php echo !empty($ProductID)?$ProductID:'';?>">
                            <?php if (!empty($ProductIDError)): ?>
                                <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $ProductIDError;?></span>
                            <?php endif;?>
                        </div>
                      </div>



                      <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($Cost)?'error':'';?>">
                        <label class="control-label">Cost</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input name="Cost" type="text"  placeholder="Cost" value="<?php echo !empty($Cost)?$Cost:'';?>">
                            <?php if (!empty($CostError)): ?>
                                <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $CostError;?></span>
                            <?php endif;?>
                        </div>
                      </div>



                      <div class="form-actions">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Daftar</button>
                          <a class="btn" href="index.bulanan.php">Menu Utama</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will need to first query your DB in order to get the values from `ProductID` and `Cost` columns, in order to be able to get the ratio to be entered in your table. Steps: Query, calculate, insert.

Comment: You also need to change `$c = "(a/b)";` to `$c = ($a/$b);` - As it stands, both "a" and "b" are treated as constants and treated as a string. If set inside quotes, `$c = "($a/$b)";` will produce (10/50) while `$c = ($a/$b);` will produce 0.2 based on using `$a = 10;
$b = 50;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you will first need to do is query your DB in order to get the values from the ProductID and Cost columns, in order to be able to get the ratio to be entered in your table.

As I've outlined in the comments area, you will need to change `$c = "(a/b)";` to `$c = ($a/$b);`

As it stands, both "a" and "b" are treated as [**constants**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) and as a string when set inside quotes.

If set inside quotes, `$c = "($a/$b)";` will produce (10/50), while `$c = ($a/$b);` will produce 0.2 based on using `$a = 10; $b = 50;`

**Steps to take:**

- Query your table
- Calculate the value from the columns (must be an int)
- Insert result value from queried table into the desired table

**Sidenote:** It's unsure what `('400', '200', '$c')` the 400 and 200 are doing in there and whether those are the numbers you wish to use as the ratio. You may need to elaborate on that.

Your ratio column will need to be as DECIMAL 50,2 / The 50 is an exaggerated number, but the 2 will be the decimal points.

**N.B.:** Ratios will produce decimals.

Additional note: `$var = "John";` below, is based on an `id` column (`VARCHAR`)

*For example:*

```
<?php

$mysql_hostname = 'xxx';   // change
$mysql_username = 'xxx';   // to
$mysql_password = 'xxx';   // your
$mysql_dbname   = 'xxx';   // own

$conn= new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$var = "John"; // based on an id column (varchar)

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT Cost, ProductID FROM calculationexample WHERE id = ?');
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $var); 
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

$a = $row['Cost'];
$b = $row['ProductID'];
$c = ($a/$b);

echo $c; // will output the ratio

            }

try {

    $prod_id = 400;
    $cost = 200;

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO calculationexample 
    (ProductID, Cost, Ratio)
    VALUES(:prod_id, :cost, :ratio)");
    $stmt->bindValue(':prod_id', $prod_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':cost', $cost,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':ratio', $c,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

echo "New record created successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: Fred, thanks for your reply. ('400','200','$c') is just a dummy value in order to perform the division function. You have point out my basic mistakes (the 'If set inside quotes, $c = "($a/$b)"; will produce (10/50), while $c = ($a/$b); will produce 0.2 based on using $a = 10; $b = 50;..'). Again, Thanks for your help fred...

Comment: Dear friends, what if im using a records field instead of variable such as the $prod_id =400 and $cost=200. I tried replacing the $prod_id = ['ProductID'] and $cost =['Cost'] but no luck..

Comment: @mahadir You would probably need to use that in the while loop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Fred.. do you mean i should put it here..                                                              while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

$a = $row['Cost'];
$b = $row['ProductID'];
$c = ($a/$b);

but here we already put the ProductID and Cost, right?

Comment: sorry for keep asking you question but im new to php.. anyway thanks for your help..